# Are singular foliations spanned by collinear vector fields equal?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, vector-fields, foliations

Let $M$ be a compact $n$-manifold (let's say with boundary, but this isn't too important), $X$ a vector field on $M$ and $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ a non-zero function on $M$.

My question: are the singular foliations spanned by $X$ and $fX$ equal? In other words, do the traces of trajectories of $X$ and $fX$ with the same starting point coincide?

I tried a couple of simple examples and checked that they do coincide, and I did a heuristic argument which works in my favor: if $p \in M$ such that $X_p = 0$, then obviously the trajectories starting at $p$ of $X$ and $fX$ coincide (it's just the point $p$). Otherwise, there exists a chart centered at $p$ where $X = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$, and so in this chart, $\phi_t^X(p) = (e^t,0,\dots,0)$. On the other hand, the flow of $fX$ starting at $p$ is locally the solution of the equation $$x' = (f(x) \cdot x_1, 0, \dots, 0), \hspace{5pt} x(0) = 0,$$and if we set $g(x_1) := f(x_1,0,\dots,0)$, then $x_1' = g(x_1)x_1$, $x_2 = \cdots = x_n = 0.$ If we define $$G(x_1) := \int \frac{dx_1}{g(x_1)x_1},$$ then, heuristically, $$x_1 = G^{-1}(t),$$ and both of the trajectories are contained in the $\{ x_2 = \cdots = x_n = 0\}$-part of the chart.

However, I don't think this is a difficult question and I'd like to see a formal argument. I suspect that the only reason that I'm unable to resolve this is because of my (very) rusty knowledge of the theory of ODE's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need some additional smoothness properties of $X$ (and $f$), but with those in hand, the answer is yes.

The reason for this answer is the *uniqueness* part of the existence and uniqueness theorem for solutions of ODE's (for example look at [Theorem 2 here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Etyson/existence.pdf)). That theorem says that if $X$ is $C^1$ then then for each initial condition $(x,v)$ ($x \in M$, $v \in T_x M$) the solution is unique over some open interval.

Now the idea is to observe that any solution for $fX$ with initial condition $(x,v)$ can be reparameterized to give a solution for $X$ with the same initial condition $(x,v)$. To put this another way, by a change of variables one converts a solution for $fX$ into a solution for $X$. The key point is that a change of variable does not affect the image set of the solution, i.e. it does not affect the trajectory as a subset of $M$.